# What broke the frequent tab?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Yesterday, the frequent question tab for every tag I follow seems to have gone completely broken. Where there used to be a nice list of canonical duplicates, I now find just a couple of canonical duplicates mixed with random trash.

See for example [C frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) or [C++ frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) tabs. It seems like the whole SO database got nuked somehow.

To my surprise, I can't find any meta thread about it, even though this severely reduces the possibility to find the good content in the flood of trash. This in turn makes me believe the problem is somehow local (which doesn't make any sense)?

Anyone else experiencing the same problem? What is the cause behind this?

Comment: Isn't the much more pertinent question *who* broke it? GET THE PITCHFORKS!

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour, though.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, as long as you're talking about new-nav. (In which case could you add the tag) @Pekka웃 - I'll get the torches!

Comment: Ok so I take it there's some new update which broke everything. Why not immediately rollback it and get the site working again then?

Comment: More importantly: why must SO constantly change things that already worked perfectly well? You are _breaking the site, you are not making it better!_

Comment: So that we can be very explicit; can you cite some question numbers from one of those lists, indicating ideally one of the "random trash", and one of the "canonical answers" ? and ideally describing what (in your view) makes the one random trash? I want to check the logic, but being *explicit* would really help me check your expectations against the code

Comment: @MarcGravell Will update question with some examples.

Comment: @Lundin don't stress on that, actually; I think I know what is going on. It didn't help that there is also a fun F5 bug that was confusing matters...

Comment: @Lundin please try again now; fix is deployed

Comment: @MarcGravell Indeed, it seems to be completely restored now.

Comment: @Lundin sorry for that; and thanks for reporting it - it was not an intentional cheese-movage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that would be me. I had one damned job... to sort questions correctly. Well, as part of the new-nav changes, we implemented a new optimized sorting algorithm that is much faster at getting the first page or the last page out of a vast list (using arbitrary and complicated filtering and sorting - not just the list's existing order - that would be too easy!).

And... it was broken. I know, I know... don't implement sorting algorithms! But there was a legitimate reason, and it was *almost* right - but yet wrong, in fun and subtle ways.

I am deploying some changes that should resolve this.

Comment: Does SO / SE have a testing environment?

Comment: @Trobbins We have an infrastructure setup that lets us play with changes on internal QA setups (separate to local development), and we can usually use "meta" for smoke-testing, plus with have the "alpha" program, and tools for A/B testing etc - but occasionally something gets through without being noticed. On this occasion, it was just particularly gnarly.